# Unable to track time spent on React web app with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, react-ga

I have built a React web app and I would like to track the users time spent on my website using Google Analytics.

Currently I am using `react-ga` (https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga) as a tool to bind the Google Analytics with React. I have successfully tracked each page with Google Analytics. I can see the traffic sources and overview like this: 
[Google Analytics Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6IRN.png)

However, when I checked the Avg. Time Spent page: [Google Analytics Behavior overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsO4T.png).  I can not see any data on avg. time spent.

The following is what I have set up in my code, I initialized the ReactGA in my App.js file:

**App.js**

```
componentDidMount() {
    ReactGA.initialize('UA-xxxxxxx-x')
    ....
}
```

And I tracked my pages like this in my Routing.js file where I have all my react routers routes in this file:

**Routing.js**

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.history.listen(location => ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname))
  ...
}
```

So far this is all I have set up for `react-ga` for Google Analytics.

Do I miss anything for tracking the Avg. time spent on my site?

Answer (score 0):

You can use timing api:
Allow to measure periods of time such as AJAX requests and resources loading by sending hits using the analytics.js library.

```
ReactGA.timing({
  category: 'JS Libraries',
  variable: 'load',
  value: 20, // in milliseconds
  label: 'CDN libs'
});
```

This is equivalent to the following Google Analytics command:

```
ga('send', 'timing', 'JS Libraries', 'load', 20, 'CDN libs');
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-timings